Can I use copyleft-licensed library in MIT-licensed project?
Can I use copyleft-licensed (for example, GPL-2.0) library in MIT-licensed project in the following cases:
a) Library files are located in project's repository directly;
b) Library files are not present in project's repo, but they need to be installed from manager (for example, pip);
c) Library is in the git submodule inside project's repository on GitHub;
d) Library files are not present in project's repo, but they are required to build the project?
Sorry if this question is stupid, I am not very experienced in licensing.

You stated GPL as an example of a copyleft license.
There are several types of copyleft licenses:

Very strong copyleft (AGPLv3)
Strong copyleft (GPLv2, GPLv3)
Weak copyleft (LGPLv2.1, LGPLv3)
Very weak copyleft (MPL2)

As stated in Philip's answer, the repo layout doesn't matter at all.
In fact, whether you distribute the copyleft-licensed library together with your MIT-licensed software also does not matter.
What matters is the method by which the copyleft license affects the MIT-licensed software.
If the copyleft license's viral effects depend on the creation of a derivative work (based on copyright law), then the creator of the license would likely define the application of this to the specific technologies in some manner. The GNU Foundation (for GPL, AGPL and LGPL) and the Mozilla Foundation (for MPL2) do this through their respective FAQs.
For AGPL and GPL, as long as the MIT-licensed software depends on the strong copyleft-licensed library through linking (either dynamic or static), the MIT-licensed software too must be distributed based on the conditions of the strong copyleft license (and therefore, making the MIT-licensed software become (A)GPL-licensed). Here, "linking" is implicitly based on how C/C++ linking works.
From GPL FAQ:

Does the GPL have different requirements for statically vs dynamically
linked modules with a covered work? (#GPLStaticVsDynamic)
No. Linking a GPL covered work statically or dynamically with other
modules is making a combined work based on the GPL covered work. Thus,
the terms and conditions of the GNU General Public License cover the
whole combination. See also What legal issues come up if I use
GPL-incompatible libraries with GPL software?

Meanwhile for LGPL, as long as the MIT-licensed software depends on the weak copyleft-licensed library through linking (either dynamic or static), the licensee is obliged to make it possible to modify the library (using its source code) and re-link the modified library to the MIT-licensed software. This is much simpler with dynamic linking. Here, "linking" is again implicitly based on how C/C++ linking works.
From GPL FAQ:

Does the LGPL have different requirements for statically vs
dynamically linked modules with a covered work? (#LGPLStaticVsDynamic)
For the purpose of complying with the LGPL (any extant version: v2,
v2.1 or v3):
(1) If you statically link against an LGPLed library, you must also
provide your application in an object (not necessarily source) format,
so that a user has the opportunity to modify the library and relink
the application.
(2) If you dynamically link against an LGPLed library already present
on the user's computer, you need not convey the library's source. On
the other hand, if you yourself convey the executable LGPLed library
along with your application, whether linked with statically or
dynamically, you must also convey the library's sources, in one of the
ways for which the LGPL provides.

Meanwhile, MPL2 is a file-level copyleft license. It has nothing to do with linking. As long as an individual file is licensed under MPL2, any modification to it could be considered the creation of a derivative work, and that modified file must be redistributed based on the conditions of the MPL2.
This is good, as there are no effects based on the method of linking, plus isolation of the effect of a license to individual files makes it technology-agnostic (i.e. we don't need to interpret what "linking" means in Bash or Python compared to C for example).
From MPL2 FAQ:

Q12: How does the scope of the MPL's copyleft compare with the LGPL
and GPL's copyleft?
Broadly speaking, the scope of the MPL, LGPL, and GPL can be
summarized this way:
MPL: The copyleft applies to any files containing MPLed code.
LGPL: The copyleft applies to any library based on LGPLed code.
GPL: The copyleft applies to all software based on GPLed code.
However, we would recommend reading the licenses to
better understand their
scope, and in particular, to understand how the LGPL
and GPL define "based on."


"the creator of the license would likely define the application of this to the specific technologies in some manner." I disagree with this specific point - the FSF can write whatever they like in their FAQs, but that has no bearing on whether something is a derivative work or not.

Something which bears repeating: how you lay out the files in your repository has zero impact on copyright, so the answer will be the same, no matter which of (a) to (d) you choose.
The question you need to answer is whether your project is a derivative work of the copyleft work. The generally (but not universally) accepted answer is that if it's part of one program, it's one work and you must follow the GPL requirements. It sounds very much like you're making one program, so the answer is "no, you cannot do this; you must license the whole work under the GPL".

I think it's fine to license parts of it (that you added) under the MIT license, what matters is that it must be a GPL-compatible license so that you can provide the combination of everything under the applicable GPL version. As opposed to your "you must license the whole work under the GPL" that'd allow others to choose between the MIT license or the applicable GPL for your original additions. That is if (parts of) your additions can be used independently of the copylefted parts, of course.

@ecm I fully agree with what you're saying, but feel it's a subtlety which has no practical import in most cases, similar to how the answer is actually "yes, the poster can use a GPL licensed library in a MIT licensed project, but they can never distribute it".

Eh I think it could matter, or at least seem like it matters. For example: OP writes a program that uses a GPL-licensed library, then later changes their program to use a different, MIT-licensed library which provides similar functionality, instead of the GPL one. OP now wants to distribute their program under MIT. The answer might lead OP to think they could not do so, because their original program was a derivative of the GPL library so must be under GPL, and the changed version is a derivative of the original version so must also be under GPL. ecm's comment suggests that they could, though.

Hmm, OP might imply (perhaps unconsciously^^) that the structure is also different in the options they present. For instance, one way it could work is if the project they write does not explicitly use the GPL library, but offers a way to use both together without distributing them together. E.g. they could write an interface that you could easily plug the GPL library into, but you could also write your own implementation or the like. If they didn't mean that, well then @t1m013y take this as a hint towards a potential way to separate both projects so it's not one program...

@FrankHopkins that wouldn't exempt you from the GPL's obligations with respect to your code.  GPL obligations are not affected by your shipping arrangements.

@MadHatter sure, but how would the GPL apply to a code project that contains no part of a GPL project? Just because a user can then combine it with a GPL project?That's then an issue the user of your project has, not you as the developer / distributor. As the answer argues, the GPL would apply if it is "one" program, which it then would no longer be.

There's a lot of stuff written about the use of shim code to try to separate GPL code from other code, and thus avoid the copyleft obligations applying to the whole package.  Feel free to google it, or if you prefer, write it up as a question here (though search here first, we already have some questions such as this) - but the discussion is quite a lot too wordy for a comments field!

Does it mean that even if my python project uses import <some_GPL_licensed_library>, I must distribute this project under GPL and can not use MIT?

@t1m013y Correct. That's the whole point of the GPL.

Why doesn't Curl use GPL license. Curl is licensed under MIT-like license, but it can use WolfSSL library, which is licensed under GPL-2.0. Is it because WolfSSL can be replaced with another libraries (for example, openSSL, which has Apache-2.0 license)?

You should ask that as a separate question if you are interested.

Of course, you are right that "how you lay out the files in your repository has zero impact on copyright," , but OP said d is "d) Library files are NOT PRESENT in project's repo, but they are required to build the project." You can't be committing copyright infringement if you don't copy or distribute the work.
